# Ubuntu Replacing Windows 8

Tags: installation, partitioning, windows-8

I had 3 Partition(C(150gb),D(350gb),E(400gb)) and Windows 8.1 installed on C drive.
I replaced Windows 8 with Ubuntu 13.04.

Now I have only one file system(900gb).

Is there any way to access data of D and E partition from Ubuntu?
Is it possible to get back D,E partition if i replace Ubuntu with windows?
Has Ubuntu formatted my entire hard disk?

```
$df -h
/dev/sda2       909G  2.7G  861G   1% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           788M  860K  787M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            3.9G  156K  3.9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   44K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1        93M  121K   93M   1% /boot/efi
```

Comment: try testdisk for recovering the datas.

Answer (score 0):

`df` will only show you mounted partitions.
I'd use `gparted` or `fdisk -l` to work out what's on a disk.

But `sda2` being so big suggests that yes, you've replaced the all old partitions instead of resizing them (or just replacing one).

You can reinstall Windows (which will likely replace Ubuntu), or attempt some sort of data recovery  but there isn't a magic way to just undo what's been done. You've overwritten data. There's usually no coming back from that.